# Error with importing self defined function

Tags: python, import

When I try to import a function from a file, it doesn't recognize the module that I imported earlier, while when its defined directly then there is no problem.

The module is imported as sr. Should I import it body of the function or is there any other trick.

```
    # doesn't work
    import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    from Chatfunctions import Listner



    Listner()
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-720eb32cc560> in <module>()
      7 
      8 
----> 9 Listner()
     10 

/Users/michalczapski/Bots/BI Bot/Chatfunctions.py in Listner()
     12     print("Botty: ",message)
     13     return None
---> 14 
     15 def Listner():
     16     with sr.Microphone() as source:

NameError: name 'sr' is not defined


    # works
    import speech_recognition as sr
    r = sr.Recognizer()


    def Listner():
        with sr.Microphone() as source:
            print("...")
            audio=r.listen(source)

          try:
            print("You: "+r.recognize_google(audio));
            return r.recognize_google(audio)
          except:
            pass;
    Listner()
```

Comment: yes, `sr` is not defined in the `Listener` function, and is not available to it by any of Python's scoping rules. essentially, you are expecting python to use dynamic scoping, it does not, it uses lexical scoping.

Comment: if the imported function uses certain module - should it be imported inside the function... but then each time i call the function the module will be imported again and again...

Comment: It will not, but still, generally a function should not import a module. You need to import the module in `Chatfunctions.py`

Answer (score 0):

All the modules used in the imported functions need to be imported in the file in which functions are defined